# Which servers does nitrous.io use? School network blocking something

Tags: nitrousio

I'm trying to get Nitrous.IO working here at my high school so I can use it to teach the Go programming language at a club. The site itself is not blocked, but when loading a box, the IDE / terminal does not connect, and I cannot make a new box. I am able to request the school's IT department to unblock sites, but I need to know what is being inhibited here. 
Any guidance would be just swell.

Comment: really a great question for their tech support, since the list can likely change

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll have to have your IT department at school unblock the websocket protocol.

You can go to:

http://websocketstest.com/

when you're on the school's network to check if websockets are supported (everything should be "checked" on that site).  Once they unblock websockets, give it another shot, you should be able to access your box.